# Alexa Skill Access Token Out of Session

Tags: oauth, alexa-skills-kit, account-linking

For an Alexa Skill user that has completed account linking - is a way to get their account linking `accessToken` outside of the skill session?

For example I know that as part of the out of session [Skill Messaging API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-messaging-api-reference.html#obtain-the-skill-messaging-token) - you can do this to get the `skillMessagingToken`:

```
SKILL_CLIENT_ID='YOUR_SKILL_CLIENT_ID'
SKILL_CLIENT_SECRET='YOUR_SKILL_CLIENT_SECRET'
API_URL='https://api.amazon.com/auth/O2/token'
curl -k -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -d "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=alexa:skill_messaging&client_id=$SKILL_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=$SKILL_CLIENT_SECRET" \
    $API_URL
```

Rather than using the scope `alexa:skill_messaging` maybe there’s another scope value that returns the user's account linking `accessToken`?

Answer (score 0):

Any scope provides an access token. The scope determines what you can do with the access token, not whether or not you get one.

#### Edit

The "out of session" example above retrieves a token assigned to your skill, not a specific user. But the account linking access token is assigned to a specific customer and is returned from a successful authorization from the customer.

There is a linking workflow that doesn't necessarily involve a skill session or the Alexa app.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/app-to-app-account-linking-starting-from-your-app.html

As for the scope, you specify that in the skill linking config in your skill config. So the scope is what *you* specify. For Login with Amazon, the basic profile scope is usually all that's needed as it will give you a unique user ID for the customer that will be the same across your skill and your external app(s).

Comment: I mean specifically the access token that is stored within the Alexa service after account linking.